Postfix: Is always_bcc always sent as nobody?
Trying to use always_bcc for its most common use: archive mail.
always_bcc = mailarchive@localhost 

This fails with permission errors.
 postfix/local[2798499]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=65534/65534: create maildir file {$HOMEDIR}1732630339.P2798499.{$HOSTNAME} Permission denied

This shows the 'local' daemon is correctly invoked.
To make things 'work' I had to use this hack, which is less than ideal because it restricts postfix to delivering locally to only one user in this way:
always_bcc = mailarchive@localhost
default_privs = mailarchive

aliases:
postmaster:    root
mailarchive:    /mnt/archive/mail/

Why can't postfix find my user and keeps delivering as nobody unless I force override it? The user mailarchive exists locally alright. The mails find their way to /mnt/archive/mail/. What else is needed to add them?
Previously, I tried this more 'normal' way as well:
Either leave 'aliases' with just the postmaster line or add this (which afaik is redundant):
postmaster:    root
mailarchive:   mailarchive

Then comment or leave out #default_privs = mailarchive in main.cf, restart postfix. The result is still trying to make files as nobody:
warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=65534/65534: create maildir file /mnt/sdb1/mail/tmp/1733213298.P3327543.acme.com: Permission denied
2B77EE075: to=<mailarchive@bsmtp.acme.com>, orig_to=<mailarchive@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.32, delays=0.28/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /mnt/sdb1/mail/tmp/1733213298.P3327543.bsmtp.acme.com: Permission denied)

If I really need to tell postfix that mailarchive@localhost is the linux user mailarchive at localhost... then where? Everything online points to aliases, but that clearly isn't the place.

What have you done to confirm that user can indeed write to their mail directory?

@anx Please read the question completely. The messages are delivered when postfix is set with default_privs = mailarchive. This comment is pointless.

Wait, you mean the first test was also done with the hardcoded path, instead of that users mail directory? In that case, you have your answer. Postfix does not assume a users privileges just because the directory happens to match their mail directory.

Use a username for aliasing and let postfix determine its mail directory. A directory is not translated back to a username. Once postfix is no longer delivering on behalf of a user (triggered by a superuser-owned database) delivery is done with default privileges.

DELIVERY RIGHTS
Deliveries  to  external  files  and  external  commands  are  made with the rights of the
receiving user on whose behalf the delivery is made.  In the absence of  a  user  context,
the  local(8)  daemon uses the owner rights of the :include: file or alias database.  When
those files are owned by the superuser, delivery is made with the  rights  specified  with
the default_privs configuration parameter.

Emphasis mine, from man 8 local

I've already tried the normal configuration, and updated the question with further info. This does not work. Always_bcc to the same host is not delivered on behalf of a user.

(To make it clear: just setting the always_bcc, configuring the mailarchive user's homedir to the external drive and letting postfix figure it out also leads to mail sent as nobody).
